# Split bash command parameters in a smart and clean way

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, split

My final goal is to iterate in a clean way over all the parameters used in the last command line in bash, in order to find any path to a directory.
Example of what I would wish:

```
$ cp some_file.txt /some/existing/folder; touch a_new_file.txt
$ my_find_func
Found "/some/existing/folder" in the last command.
```

My problem is about splitting the last command in a right way, in order to handle all possible cases. Now i'm using something like this:

```
function myfunc()
{
    last_com="$(history|tail -n2|head -n1|sed -n 's/^\s*[0-9]*\s*//p')"
    eval "args=( $last_com )"
    # Note: I don't care about the security issue that eval can cause

    for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}
```

I like the *simplicity* of using `eval` in this way because it handles automatically quoted parameters, escaped spaces, glob expansion, etc... So I don't have to handle this by myself with a complicated `awk` or `sed` command.

It works fine with single commands, like this:

```
/afac/soq $ cd ..
/afac $ myfunc 
cd
..
/afac $ touch "some file.txt"
/afac $ myfunc 
touch
some file.txt
```

But obviously (because of ';' inside the array definition), it fails when I use multiple commands in a single line:

```
$ touch a_file; rm a_file
$ myfunc
bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'
$ touch a_file && rm a_file
$ myfunc
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '&&'
```

So to make it work, I would to have to split the command string into parts when `;`, `&&` or `||` is encountered, without forgetting the case when these tokens are escaped or quoted, then saying goodbye to *simplicity*... I don't even know if I'm able yet to parse this in a good way, with the current knowledge I have about `sed` and `awk`...

What would be the most clean (and easiest) solution to get all the parameters of a command into an array, handling the possibility of quoted parameters, escaped characters, *and* multiple commands on a single-line?

It's maybe quite duplicate, but I didn't find any real solution anywhere.

Comment: So, what is the expected contents of your `args` array on commands like this: `echo '1 2 3' && echo "A B" C`

Comment: @Eugeniu Rosca: something like `( echo '1 2 3' '&&' echo "A B" C )`, or `( echo '1 2 3' echo "A B" C )`. The important thing is that each effective parameter is present, so that I can test them with some thing like `[[ -d ${args[$i]} ]]` in a loop

Comment: Instead of `eval "args=( $last_com )"`, try `IFS=' ' args=($last_com)`

Comment: Tx for helping, but it really doesn't help: it splits quoted strings with spaces into small unuseful chunks (that's why I like to use `eval` because `bash` then does all this parsing work by itself, when there's no multiple commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I am only able to produce something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

last_cmd='echo 1 2 "3 4" &  && echo "A B" C || echo D "E F" &  '

# Convert any of: &, && or || to semicolon
cmd=$(sed -e 's/&\?[ ]*&&/;/g' -e 's/&\?[ ]*||/;/g' -e 's/&[ ]*$//' <<< "$last_cmd")
# TODO: get rid of/convert any other symbols creating issues to eval
echo "processed cmd: $cmd"

# split the command string using semicolon as delimiter
IFS=';'
cmd_arr=($cmd)
IFS=' '
args=()
for onecmd in "${cmd_arr[@]}"; do
    eval "args+=($onecmd)"
done

for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

---

*Version 2*

```
last_cmd='echo 1 2 "3 4"  && echo "A B" C || echo D ["E F"] $!%#^* '

# Remove ALL special characters not having a chance to appear in a pathname
cmd=$(sed 's/[][|*^#+&$!%]//g' <<< "$last_cmd")
echo "processed cmd: $cmd"

IFS=' ' eval "args=($cmd)"
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but will set it as the answer in awhile if there's no better answer... thank you your help

Comment: Maybe someone comes with a really simple way to accomplish this. Don't mark the question as answered yet.

Comment: Because what you really want is extracting some directory/file paths from the command history, I think you can simply remove ALL special characters from the `$last_cmd`, such as: `[]|*^#+&$!%`. Check the updated version.

Comment: Very good idea; I would tweak a bit the list of chars (especially adding the semicolon), but it does the job quite well!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit better, though not all cases, with:

```
function myfunc(){
 set -- $(history 2 | sed 's/[ 0-9]*//;1q')
 for arg
 do echo "$arg"
 done
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it made me learn some things with `bash`,  but it splits words not smartly when there are spaces inside quotes; however i have to look at it a bit more